# Why would creating a new thread result in a list assertion failure?

Tags: c, multithreading, list, segmentation-fault, pthreads

I'm still a beginner with threads, and am attempting to create a fork-join pattern to read a list of csv files. I have used GDB to find where I am getting a segmentation fault, but don't really understand what the error means or what is actually going wrong.

If you need more information please let me know, but this is the error I'm getting. Any help at all would be highly appreciated!

```
493         pthread_create(&rcsv, NULL, read_csv_thread, &csv_info);
(gdb) 
[New Thread 0x7ffff6fef700 (LWP 28983)]
cfpb: ../src/lib/list.c:173: list_insert: Assertion `is_interior    (before) || is_tail (before)' failed.
495         number_of_records += state_nums[i-1];
(gdb) 

Thread 3 "cfpb" received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff6fef700 (LWP 28983)]
0x00007ffff7826418 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6)
at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:54
54  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) 
[Thread 0x7ffff6fef700 (LWP 28983) exited]
[Thread 0x7ffff77f0700 (LWP 28982) exited]

Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
The program no longer exists.
```

Comment: I'd post more of your code. You say you're getting a segfault. `gdb` should show the line number for this. What you're showing is an `assert` failure and not a segfault. If you look at `../src/lib/list.c`, line 173, you should see `assert(is_interior(before) || is_tail(before))` The assert is a debug tool that checks that a given condition is true. So, it means that `before` did not have the required criteria that the assert wanted.

Comment: @CraigEstey When i run the program normally I get a segmentation fault, does this mean I have an assert failure which is most likely leading to my code having a seg fault? Also I will try to post my code. Thank you!

Comment: You post, I fix :-) Because of the discrepancy in behavior running with/without `gdb`, you probably have a race condition between your threads. This is [usually] easy to diagnose with the full code. Also, lists (e.g. singly linked, doubly linked) require extra stuff to work correctly between threads. This accounts for the `assert` failure as well

Comment: I doubt the creation of the new thread is causing the segfault,, it's most likely happening inside the function the thread is running.  Post your code if you want some help.